# Some bugs in the php code in our own SDK

Tags: php

I feel that there is an error on the following code:

```
<? $guarantee_per_inst = bcdiv( $guarantee, sizeof($installments), 2 );
        foreach ($installments as $inst) {
            $amount = bcadd( $inst['amount'], $guarantee_per_inst, 2 );
            echo "<li>".date('j.n.',time()+$inst['time_days']*3600*24)." ".$amount." &euro;</li>";
        } ?>
```

The front-end looks something like this:

> The installments are as follows:
>   ".date('j.n.',time()+$inst['time_days']*3600*24)." ".$amount." €"; } ?>

Instead of those codes, I should get a proper data.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you have not installed PHP on your server.

Comment: Are short php open tags enabled? BTW you should never ever rely on this even if it is.

Comment: Hi, 
Yes, I haven't configure the short_open_tag. Thanks! :)

By using a complete PHP tag, it works.

Thanks Jan Kruger and other guys for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

If PHP is installed and active, the most likely cause is that its config option `short_open_tag` is not enabled, so that `<?` does not work as intended. Try using `<?php` instead.

Comment: Thanks,
I didn't realize that. :D
Sometime, small things make bigger difference. Thanks!

BR
Barun.